# How to arrange multiple plots in a row in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, grid, row, wolfram-mathematica

I have plots that look like the following:

```
Plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[{A[t]} /. Solve], {t, 0, xaxis}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> {"A"}, PlotStyle -> {Green}]
Plot2 = Plot[Evaluate[{B[t]} /. Solve], {t, 0, xaxis}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> {"B"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}]
Plot3 = Plot[Evaluate[{C[t]} /. Solve], {t, 0, xaxis}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> {"C"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange}]
Plot4 = Plot[Evaluate[{D[t]} /. Solve], {t, 0, xaxis}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> {"D"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red}]
```

Notice that the plots have free axes-limits..and I want to keep it that way. I want to arrange all the plots in a linear row, so that I can fit it on the screen. I tried `Table` like suggested in other answers, but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `GraphicsRow`?

Comment: See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35193/ugly-output-when-combining-2-plots-with-graphicsrow).